# a proof of constants are null from a given inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality

**Problem:** given constants $a,b\text{ and }c$, and a variable $x$, assume that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ holds that $|ax^2+bx+c|\le|x|^3$, then proof that $a=b=c=0$

**My try:** substitute $x=0$ into the inequality i get that $|c|\le0\Rightarrow c=0$, however i dont know how to proof that $a$ and $b$ will be $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already know that $c=0$, then $|ax^2+bx|=|ax+b|\cdot|x|\leq|x|^3$ and thus $|ax+b|\leq|x|^2$ for all $x\neq 0$.  But because $|ax+b|$ is continuous, this implies $|a\cdot0+b|=0$ and thus $b=0$.  Now repeat.

Answer (score 1):

You have found $c=0$, so $|ax^2+bx|\le |x|^3, \forall x$ implies $|ax+b|\le |x|^2$ then using the similar manner like proving $c=0$ yo'll get $b=0$. So so $|a|\le |x|, \forall x$ implies $a=0$.